# Unnecessary new lines to the output string, Python, How to get rid of these line breaks?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, concatenation

I have a user.txt with the following contents:

```
user1:M0024132132

user2:M00123132

user3:M001234123

user4:123123
```

I wrote a python code to perfom a basic string concatenation operation

```
filename='user.txt'
separator=":"
fileIN = open(filename, "r")
line = fileIN.readline()

while line:
    sout=line.split(separator)
   user=sout[0]
   passwd=sout[1]
   print ('create:' + str(user) + ':' + str(passwd) + ':::' + str(user) + ':/home/' + str(user) + ':/bin/bash:::::' )
    line = fileIN.readline()
```

Expected Output:

> create:user:M00123132:::user:/home/user:/bin/bash:::::
>   create:user1:M00123132:::user1:/home/user1:/bin/bash:::::
>   create:useruser1:M00212312:::useruser1:/home/useruser1:/bin/bash:::::
>   create:sdfsdf:12312:::sdfsdf:/home/sdfsdf:/bin/bash:::::

But I'm getting output as:

> create:user:M00123132
>
> :::user:/home/user:/bin/bash:::::
>
> create:user1:M00123132
>
> :::user1:/home/user1:/bin/bash:::::
>
> create:useruser1:M00212312
>
> :::useruser1:/home/useruser1:/bin/bash:::::

Kindly help me in solving this.

Comment: Readline always keeps '\n' at te end of line, except for the last line, just remove it with rstrip() or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3, you can use the [`end`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) keyword argument to suppress newlines:

```
print ('create:' + str(user) + ':' + str(passwd) + ':::' + str(user) 
       + ':/home/' + str(user) + ':/bin/bash:::::', end="")
```

By the way, you could simply use:

```
user, passwd = line.split(separator)
```

instead of using an intermediate list variable (ie. `sout`).

Comment: I believe, while parsing the data from the text file, its adding a newline at the end of each letter for the passwd variable. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: You can try using `passwd.strip()` to see if it helps in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip the line to get rid of the new line. The readline API reads the new line. This new line later ends up being part of the passwd variable.

```
while line:
    line = line.strip()
```

From Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

> f.readline() reads a single line from the file; a newline character
>   (\n) is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the last
>   line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline.